# How to remove first comma on each line in a file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Remove first comma on each line  in a file. I presume sed is needed.

Comment: show some samples!. and show your desired output.!

Comment: For example:  "I love to have wild, sex with 3 man at the same time" should convert to "I love to have wild sex with 3 man at the same time"

Comment: "Let's eat grandpa!" vs. "Let's eat, grandpa !" ... commas - they save lives ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sed

```
sed -i.bak 's/,//' file
```

awk

```
awk '{sub(",","")}1' file >temp; mv temp file
```

shell

```
while read -r line
do
 echo "${line/,/}"
done <"file" > temp
mv temp file
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sed will do it.

```
sed s/,// < filename
```

Comment: This will only remove first first comma :(

Comment: @Dennis Williamson true, but I realized that too late; I can't edit now while the behavior is still in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

For first comma:

`sed '/,//' < file`

If first comma is first character:

`sed '/^,//' < file`

Comment: My answer is contingent if you are using a *NIX OS. If not, well I am sure somebody will post a powershell answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

first comma
sed '/,//' < file

first character that is a comma
sed '/^,//' < file

[USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^,//' < file
```

Comment: awk '{sub(",","")}1' file >temp; mv temp file

Comment: this checks for a string with a comma as its first character and remove it. its is not the same as "first" comma